# present perfect tense vs Present perfect continous tense usage

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

> 1)I **have been waiting** to do this for a long time.

> 2)I **have waited** to do this for a long time.

Which one is correct? If both are correct, what is the difference in meaning between them??

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct, but the present perfect continuous can be used to emphasize the length of time that has passed in your example.
I think they have the explicit difference when we're talking about how or many.
Example:
"She has drunk 3 cups of beer" is correct
'She has been drinking 3 cups of beer" is incorrect.

Comment: so both mean the same thing without any difference except the emphasis??

Comment: Yes. In addition, when present perfect continuous doesn't contains a duration of time like "for a long time/for 2 weeks", it means that action has been happening "recently" or "lately":)